# How to join 2 row together in a same dictionary c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have declare a dictionary with the key on INT and the value of a class
`Dictionary<int, List<clsBook>> dicBook = new Dictionary<int, List<clsBook>>();`

I would like to perform a join of  row in the dictionary when a certain value is equal to the second row .

My Code is as below , but I getting error "Cannot implicitly convert type System.collections.generic.list < System.collections.generic.list < clsBOOK > > to System.Collections.Generic.List< clsBook >"

```
            List<clsBook> aaa = (from OD in dicBook
                             join OD2 in dicBook
                             on OD.Value[1] equals OD2.Value[1]
                             select OD.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It seems to be pointless to join on the same value in the same dictionary, isn't it? Apart from that, `SelectMany` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary` exposes an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, since your `TValue` is `List<clsBook>` you will end up with a an `List<List<clsBook>` which cannot be assigned to `List<clsBook>`.

If you can describe what you are trying to achieve, as this is not obvious to me, then I may be able to help more.

Even if you use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) to essentially concatenate the lists, I see no logic in what you are trying to achieve.

Do you want to merge all lists that share the same first element? What you are doing will result in at least a doubling of each list in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
var  dicBook = new Dictionary<int, List<clsBook>>();
           List<List<clsBook>> aaa = (from OD in dicBook
                                join OD2 in dicBook
                                on OD.Value[1] equals OD2.Value[1]
                                select OD.Value).ToList();
```

Hope this Helps.